# Build failure while trying to use docker-compose build step

Tags: selenium, docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose

I am trying to execute my selenium test on Jenkins node (Ubuntu) which has docker already installed. I added docker-compose build step plugin to my Jenkins project. When i try to build the project, I am getting an error in console -
$ docker-compose -f /home/jenkins/workspace/OM/TestWDM/docker-compose.yml up -d
Build step 'Docker Compose Build Step' changed build result to FAILURE

I am able to execute the project successfully on my local machine. I do have docker-compose.yml file in the root directory. I tried docker ps -a command just to see if it's partially . working, but it's not.

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
   selenium-hub:
     restart: always
     image: selenium/hub:latest
     ports:
       - "4444:4444"
   #selenium-chrome
   selenium-chrome:
     restart: always
     image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
     stdin_open: true
     links:
       - selenium-hub:hub
   #selenium-firefox
   selenium-firefox:
     restart: always
     image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
     links:
       - selenium-hub:hub

   chrome:
       image: selenium/node-chrome
       depends_on:
         - selenium-hub
       environment:
         - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
         - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444

   firefox:
       image: selenium/node-firefox
       depends_on:
         - selenium-hub
       environment:
         - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
         - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
```

The reason I am trying to use docker here because I was facing an issue with chrome binary not found without it. My expectation over here was to have my test run successfully on Jenkins node.

Comment: Does your ubuntu server have docker-compose installed as well? I know some docker installations may not come bundled with docker-compose.

Comment: I am assuming it does. Is there a way to check if it's installed for not?

Comment: Yes, you can run `docker-compose -version` or the right version flag

Comment: I don't have physical access to the slave machine. and docker-compose command is not acceptable in shell script via Jenkins. So, not sure how can I check the version as suggested by you.

Comment: Add it to a sh step if using pipelines or a execute shell build step if using something else in jenkins